# Trying to manipulate the saturation on a image on OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to create a Lpr algorithm in Opencv. I'm applying to the image things like grayscale and canny; but also I need to apply saturation to the image, and that is my issue:

This is the code (I extract this code from this page http://hasanaga.info/tag/opencv-saturation/):

```
void saturation(cv::Mat &img)
{
    Mat imagen;
    cvtColor(img,imagen,CV_RGB2HSV);

    for(int y=0; y<imagen.cols; y++)
    {
        for(int x=0; x<imagen.rows; x++)
        {
            int cur2 = imagen.at<Vec3b>(Point(y,x))[1];
            cur2 += 41;
            if(cur2 < 0) cur2= 0; else if(cur2 > 255) cur2 = 255;
            imagen.at<Vec3b>(Point(y,x))[1] = cur2;
        }
    }

    cvtColor(imagen,img,CV_HSV2RGB);

}
```

(I change a little bit the code, cause I don't need to change the other parameters)

But when I try to create the executable, this happen:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((scn == 3 || scn == 4) && (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F)) in cvtColor, file /home/guerrero/opencv2.4.9/opencv-2.4.9/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 3959
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>     what():  /home/guerrero/opencv2.4.9/opencv-2.4.9/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3959: error: (-215) (scn == 3 || scn == 4) && (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) in function cvtColor

May I know what cause the error?

Comment: Looks like your image is not in the proper format.

Comment: Try to check which one of the 2 conversions did trigger the exception, then check (look at/print) the type of its source image (it can be `img` or `imagen` depending on which call caused the error. Since `cvtColor` usually preserves the image type, an educated guess is that `img` is either empty or single channel when you call the `saturation()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Number of channels or depth of input Image is not correct..

src channels should be 3 or 4, depth should be either CV_8U or CV_32F

```
((scn == 3 || scn == 4) && (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F))
```